# Узнать город и дату рождения

Tags: javascript, jquery, vkontakte-api

Получаю данные вместо города `[object Object]` и вместо даты рождения `undefined` все остальное нормально выводиться.
В чем особенность,подскажите.

```
    $(function output(){


 function gotData( data){
    var i, post, html="";
    if( !data  ||  !data.response  ||  !data.response.items) {
        console.error( "VK returned some crap:", data);
        return;
    }
    for( i=0; i<data.response.items.length; i++) {
       info = data.response.items[i];
        html += '<div class="post well">'+info.city+info.sex+info.sex+info.first_name+info.bdate+'</div>';

    }
    $('#v').html(html);
};


$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers",
    data: {
        group_id: "habr",
        fields:"city,sex,sex",
        v: "5.27",
        offset:0,
        count:5
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",    
    success: gotData,
});
});
```

Comment: Вы через console.log объект info выведите и посмотрите что в нем. Видимо город не одним полем идет а несколькими и поле с датой как нибудь по другому называется

Comment: _"В чем особенность,подскажите."_ -- `fields:"city,sex,sex"` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не у всех указан bdate, поэтому может выводить undefined

---

```
info.city.title + " " + info.first_name + " " + info.bdate + " " + info.sex
```

---

```
data: {
  group_id: "habr",
  fields:"city,sex,bdate",
  v: "5.27",
  offset:0,
  count:5
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже подсказали, пользуйтесь console.log для отладки.
info.city - объект, название города хранится в поле title.
И внизу у вас ошибка в указании запрашиваемых полей.

```
function gotData...
    html += '<div class="post well">' + info.city.title + info.sex + info.first_name + info.bdate + '</div>';
...
ajax...    
    fields:"city, sex, bdate",
...
```

Comment: Спасибо,выручили!